# how to delete an object from an array without changing the array type to object

Tags: sql, laravel

Doing a check later with foreach. I already need to do it for the url, so as I don't know how to do it in the query, I also did it within this loop. Which is to remove the entire object that has the 3 columns with a value of 0. However, when I do this, the $posts array changes to an object and I can no longer convert it correctly to an array.

```
$posts = Post::query();
        $posts = $posts->leftJoin('likes', 'posts.id', '=', 'likes.post_id');
        $posts = $posts->leftJoin('shares', 'posts.id', '=', 'shares.post_id');
        $posts = $posts->leftJoin('comments', 'posts.id', '=', 'comments.post_id');
        $posts = $posts->selectRaw('posts.id, posts.page, posts.slug, posts.title as publicacao, COUNT(likes.id) AS curtidas, COUNT(shares.id) AS compartilhamentos, COUNT(comments.id) AS comentarios');
        $posts = $posts->groupBy('posts.id', 'posts.page', 'posts.slug', 'posts.title');
        $posts = $posts->get();



        foreach ($posts as $key => $post) {
            if($post->curtidas > 0 && $post->compartilhamentos > 0 && $post->comentarios > 0){
                $pages = Post::whichPage();
                $post->url = 'https://blogavozdocliente.com.br/blog/' . $pages[$post->page] . '/' . $post->id . '/' . $post->slug; 
    
                unset($post->id);
                unset($post->page);
                unset($post->slug);
            }
            else{
                unset($posts[$key]);
            }
        }


        return response()->json($posts);
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way to do the verification directly during the consultation.

```
$posts = Post::query();
        $posts = $posts->leftJoin('likes', 'posts.id', '=', 'likes.post_id');
        $posts = $posts->leftJoin('shares', 'posts.id', '=', 'shares.post_id');
        $posts = $posts->leftJoin('comments', 'posts.id', '=', 'comments.post_id');
        $posts = $posts->selectRaw('posts.id, posts.page, posts.slug, posts.title as publicacao, COUNT(likes.id) AS curtidas, COUNT(shares.id) AS compartilhamentos, COUNT(comments.id) AS comentarios');
        $posts = $posts->groupBy('posts.id', 'posts.page', 'posts.slug', 'posts.title');
        $posts = $posts->havingRaw('COUNT(likes.id) != 0 or COUNT(shares.id) != 0 or COUNT(comments.id) != 0');
        $posts = $posts->get();


        foreach ($posts as $key => $post) {
                $pages = Post::whichPage();
                $post->url = 'https://blogavozdocliente.com.br/blog/' . $pages[$post->page] . '/' . $post->id . '/' . $post->slug; 
    
                unset($post->id);
                unset($post->page);
                unset($post->slug);
        }
```

Comment: Good you found a different way to go about it. Check out the linked duplicate question/answer if you want an explanation to your original issue as to why the json data was showing as an object instead of an array.